# Is there a way to run tests prerequisite once and clean up in the end in whole unit test run

Tags: python, pytest, nosetests, python-unittest, unittest2

I'm running series of testcases in multiple files, but I want to run the prereq and cleanup only once through out the run, please let me know is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

py.test -> session scoped fixtures and their finalization should help you

You can use conftest.py to code your fixture.